# Mysql Query with calculation on each result row

Tags: mysql

for my E-commerce warehouse, I'm trying to list products to prepare before shipment. I work with very low stock and for the rest on "just in time" so I've to prepare products that are in stock. Actually it works pretty well but I can't figure out how to list same product on multiple orders and products in stock even if not in enough quantity (2 ordered, 1 in stock).
Before ordering I've stock: prod1 = 2, prod2 = 10, prod3 = 3 (on order creation, the stock is reduced in database, so I send record status after the orders has been created)

I've simplified to maximum so there is a way to test it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_products` (
  `orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `products_model` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_quantity` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_quantity` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `orders` (`orders_id`) values (1),(2);

INSERT INTO `orders_products` (`orders_products_id`, `orders_id`, `products_id`, `products_model`, `products_quantity`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'prod1', 1),
(2, 1, 2, 'prod2', 4),
(3, 2, 3, 'prod3', 1),
(4, 2, 1, 'prod1', 2);


INSERT INTO `products` (`products_id`, `products_quantity`) VALUES
(1, -1),
(2, 6),
(3, 2);
```

So far I've simplified this query:

```
SELECT o.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_model, op.products_quantity as ordered_product_quantity,
 p.products_quantity as stock 
FROM orders_products op
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.products_id = op.products_id
ORDER BY o.orders_id
```

Now I'm trying to get the results below with prepare_qty (compulsory) and remaining stock (not compulsory but nice to have)

```
ordersId - product_id - product_model - prepare qty - ordered qty - remaining stock
1        - 1          - prod1         - 1           - 1           - 1
1        - 2          - prod2         - 4           - 4           - 6
2        - 3          - prod3         - 1           - 1           - 2
2        - 1          - prod1         - 1           - 2           - -1
```

Before ordering, I've 2x prod1 in stock. On last line (order 2, prod1), you see that the customer ordered 2x but I've only 1x left in stock since the previous item prod1 has been ordered in order 1.

Hope someone can help me out with this, as I absolutely want to avoid a PHP loop to build this table and would really learn how to do so in MySQL directly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the results that you get with that SELECT query, alongside the expected results table?